# How do I use CSS to create rounded corners in IE 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, rounded-corners

How do I use CSS to create rounded corners in IE 8? Since the CSS rule `corner-radius` doesn't work is there a solution to create rounded corners in using CSS in IE8 (or  IE6, and IE7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of research, I have found that there is a fix similar to the PNG transparancy fix available to IE6, called CSS3Pie. The website to the solution is found here: http://css3pie.com

You will simply have to add `behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);` to your css *anywhere* you wish to implement rounded corners.

```
#myAwesomeElement {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    behavior: url(path/to/pie_files/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: CSS3PIE is very solid for this; I would recommend 100%

Comment: Note that the `.htc` path is relative to the HTML page, not the CSS file. Or read the doc carefully